# jQuery .on('click') only works once

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to make a glyphicon in the `<th`>'s indicate whether you're sorting by ascending or descending values. The original glyphicon displayed is "glyphicon-menu-up".

```
<table class="table ws-table-list table-hover">
<thead class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <tr>
        <th class='hidden-sm hidden-xs'>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Amount", Model.PagedData.ActionMethod, new { pageNumber = Model.Number + 1, sortColumn = "amount", sortAscending = Model.PagedData.SortAscending, previousSortColumn = Model.PagedData.PreviousSortColumn }, new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = Model.PagedData.UpdateTargetId
                })
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
...
</table>
```

I've gotten the jQuery on('click') function to work (changing into "glyphicon-menu-down"), but it only works once. Not only that, but when the data is sorted, the glyphicon automatically reverts back to the "glyphicon-menu-up" after ~0.5 seconds by itself. (Could this have something to do with the @Ajax.ActionLink function?)

I've tried all the answers I could find on this site, including **.on, .off, .delegate, e.preventDefault**, and this format:

```
$('.ws-table-list').on('click', 'th', function() {
     console.log('click');   // This only runs once in the console
     $('span', this).toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-up glyphicon-menu-down');
});
```

I'm sure the answer is super simple but I'm just not getting it I guess. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will `th` be generating at runtime?

Comment: Sounds like something else is running. So what is updating the table? Ajax call onclick? If so that is replacing the table.... So that will change the icon so sounds like you need to figure out how to hook into that Ajax call and set the icon with that stuff.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more detail. Does anything else happen when  you click on the TH? Is the TH still the same element by the time the event bubbles up to the table?

Comment: @epascarello I think you're right, it looks like it's the `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace` that's replacing the table.

Comment: Interestingly, when I click only on the icon, it toggles as it should between the icons. However, it is when I click on the entire `<th>` that it reverts back to 'menu-up' icon. If it's being replaced, then theoretically it's not the same element, right @apokryfos?

Comment: because the click action (that is making the Ajax call) is not attached to the icon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change where you put your event listener:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ws-table-list th', function() {
     console.log('click');   // This only runs once in the console
     $('span', this).toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-up glyphicon-menu-down');
});
```

Comment: This worked as far as getting the function to run more than once, but for whatever reason the glyphicon still reverts back to 'menu-up' after .5 seconds... any ideas?

Comment: @whitney With that I can't help you as I have no idea what `@Ajax.ActionLink` does.

Comment: @whitney I don't know ASP but just a wild guess, could it be that when you click on the `th` you're doing an AJAX? If so, that means your AJAX call reverts it back after ~0.5 seconds.